# Un-handled rejection from promise.each

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to make multiple database queries using bluebird's Promise.each(). The part where I'm stuck is that I'm not able to handle all the rejections (if multiple promises fail). If I do the same thing using Promise.all() it works fine(It will! because in Promise.all() if 1 promise fails the result is rejected too). My question is:
How should I handle rejections in Promise.each()?

```
function foo(bar){
  return new Promise(resolve, reject){
  var query = "elect count(*) from students Where 1=1";//DELIBRATE MISTAKE
  connection.query(query, function(err, result){
    if(err){reject(err)}resolve(result);
  })
 }
}
function api(req, res){
  var tasks = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
     tasks.push(foo(bar));
  }
  Promise.each(tasks).catch(err=>{return err;});
  res.send('message')
}
```

Response:
`Unhandled rejection Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR`

Comment: What I can think is for the first rejection the catch handles the rejection and returns the error. But for the subsequent rejections there is no one to catch them.

Comment: `foo` doesn't return a promise. Where `reject` and `resolve` are defined?

Comment: @alexmac Mistake, corrected. Just wrote an example here.

Comment: Did you mean `Promise.all` (which takes an array of promises) not `Promises.each`?

Comment: All I want is a series Promise.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Bluebird#each` method incorrectly. This method do the following:

> Iterate over an array, or a promise of an array, which contains promises (or a mix of promises and values) with the given iterator function with the signature (value, index, length) where value is the resolved value of a respective promise in the input array.

So the first parameter must be an array of promises/values, and the second is a callback which accepts three parameters: `value, index, length`.

Working example:

```
let queryAsync = Promise.promisify(connection.query, { context: connection });

function foo(bar) {
  var query = 'elect count(*) from students Where 1=1'; // DELIBRATE MISTAKE
  return queryAsync(query);
}

function api(req, res){
  var tasks = [/* TODO: fill array with taskIds or something else*/];

  Promise
    .each(tasks, task => foo(task))
    .then(() => res.send('message'))
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
}
```

In the example above I use `Bluebird#promisify` method to promisify callback-style `connection.query` function. Bluebird already presents the promisification functionality, you shouldn't create your own.

Comment: `Use Bluebird#promisify to promisify callback-style connection.query function.` How will this help and how is this different? If I'm already returning a promise from the function foo(bar). Also, I have modified the example to just show here that it is not able to handle rejections so if I use only catch with promise.each() will it be a problem?

Comment: It's only suggestion, the real issue in incorrect using of `Bluebird#each` method, I mentioned about that. What about `Bluebird#promisify`, you already using Bluebird module, why create a bicycle (I mean using `Promise` constructor), when this library already has required functionality?

Comment: `where value is the resolved value of a respective promise in the input array.` But here `tasks` is not an array of promises and neither will `task` be

Comment: It's not about the first parameter in `Bluebird#each` method - _array of promises and values_, but about the second - _callback_. This callback should return a promise, and your `foo` function returns it.